# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Unsubs

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, subscriber

If person A's email address is marked as a hard bounce and is captured in all subs, Nothing is updated in CRM. But if person A updates his email address through a custom subscription center which is then updating  CRM, Will SFMC recognize that contact as a hard bounce or will it try again?

Answer (score 9):

A subscriber must meet the following criteria in order for Marketing Cloud to stop "trying" and change the subscriber's status to "HELD"

- Three hard bounces or three soft bounces are received for the subscriber and at least 15 days have passed since the first bounce.
- If the bounce was from a trusted domain, only one hard bounce is required.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subscribers_with_enhanced_subscriber_features.htm&type=5

Now The status of a subscriber changes from Active to Unsubscribed in Marketing Cloud and the **Email Opt Out** field is enabled in Sales or Service Cloud when any of the following occurs:

A subscriber clicks the Unsubscribe link in an email or the profile center.

You click Marketing Cloud Unsubscribe on a contact, lead, or person account record in Sales or Service Cloud

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_unsubscribes.htm&type=5

In Summary, the subscriber will not be targeted if one of the condition is met
- The status in Marketing Cloud is **HELD** or **Unsubscribed**
- The Email Opt out field has been set to **TRUE** in Sales Cloud.

Hope that helps!